# Aur comment field formattings

Tags: formatting, archlinux

Supports the aur comment system formatting options like `codeblock`, *italic*, **bold** and something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer sucks but its one of the top Google results for this. Although you shouldn't spam the comments with stuff, let it be known that AUR uses similar formatting to StackOverflow and Github:

- `Code` uses backticks: surround with a single `code`  or triple ```code```
- *Italic* uses asterisks: *text*
- **Bold** uses 2 asterisks: **text**

Comment: Things getting changed over time ... Thanks @Twisty, but still the AUR guidlines have the same text for big text in comments.

Comment: The triple backticks don't seem to work any more, any ideas how to make code blocks currently? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To answer my own question (for the codeblock part):

The AUR guidelines describe this [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Feedback).

> The AUR Web Interface has a comments facility that allows users to provide suggestions and feedback on improvements to the PKGBUILD contributor. Avoid pasting patches or PKGBUILDs into the comments section: they quickly become obsolete and just end up needlessly taking up lots of space. Instead email those files to the maintainer, or even use a pastebin.